# Asymmetric sequencing | Can you sequence 250 bases on Illumina Novaseq S4 (read 2)?

Tags: dna-sequencing

I would like to sequence 250 bases on Illumina Novaseq S4 on read 2.

1. Kits of illumina come in the following sizes: https://emea.illumina.com/systems/sequencing-platforms/novaseq/specifications.html
2. You can setup the sequencer for asymmetric sequencing, so that from a standard paired-end 2*100bp kit reads 150 bases from R1, and only 50 of the R2 (or vice versa).
3. On SP kit they now support 2 x 250 bp, but not on S4.
4. On the largest S4 kit it would be theoretically possible to sequence 250 + 50.

The read quality at 150 bases is excellent, so I expect at least 200 useful bases.
​

- Did anyone try this, or could point me to relevant information?
- Can you even specify such strong asymmetry in the software?
- Very importantly: Are there any risk of losing the lane?
- Are there any other risks (other than quality issues beyond 150 bases, which i assume I can easily trim away)?

ps.: Cross posted on [seqanswers](https://www.seqanswers.com/forum/sequencing-technologies-companies/illumina-solexa/324964-asymmetric-sequencing-on-illumina-novaseq-s4-beyond-specification-cycle-transferring) for a possibly more appropriate audience.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this on [MiSeq](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4417122/) and [NextSeq](https://genome.cshlp.org/content/28/8/1169) though it was several years now. It is possible to [specify cycle numbers in the GUI input](https://support.illumina.com/content/dam/illumina-support/documents/documentation/system_documentation/novaseq/1000000019358_17_novaseq-6000-system-guide.pdf) (page 54) *in theory*, unless they changed things (though they only mention up to 151 cycles).

I previously emailed Illumina technical support about this (the docs for the NextSeq also said "up to 151 cycles") and they said this:

> The reason the MiSeq 300 cycle kit supports for 250x50 is because the MiSeq chemistry has been tested at those long run lengths and the same chemistry is implemented in the 500 cycle kit that allows for 2x250. In the case of the NextSeq, there is no 500 cycle kit and it has not been tested for run lengths beyond 151. That said, there should not be anything in the software that prevents you from running a 250x50 on a NextSeq 300 cycle kit, but the quality for any cycles past 150 may be low.

It might be worth following up with them to make sure that it would still work.

For our application, the quality was sufficiently good that we were able to use the data (from a capture panel). Admittedly, we were using a somewhat bespoke alignment strategy rather than e.g. traditional variant calling.

Comment: Thank you so mcu!  We also used asymmetry in other setups,  without problems, but at the end we went with standard settings here - it was too expensive to risk anything going wrong!